# Apple Macbook pro differences

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

What is the difference between an Apple Macbook pro ME 293LL/A and an Apple Macbook pro ME 293D/A?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there any difference between part numbers?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121287/is-there-any-difference-between-part-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

D/A has a German keyboard, LL/A has the American keyboard.